# as3 stop event propagation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm having trouble getting events to stop propagating in as3 when I'm adding a new event listener in an event listener.  My second event listener is being called when I don't want it to.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, firstlistener);

function firstlistener(e:Event)
{
    //do stuff
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, secondlistener);
}
```

Comment: If this code is your real code, there's a syntax error : it's not e.stopImidiatePropagation();
 but e.stopImediatePropagation();

Comment: not my real code thats just a typo

Comment: Actually, you both have typos. It is stopImmediatePropagation() ... notice the two m's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add both `firstListener` and `secondListener` at the same time, but set the priority for the first to be higher.  That way it can conditionally stop propagation to the second.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, firstlistener, false, 100);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, secondlistener);

function firstlistener(e:Event)
{
    if (...condition...) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}
```

but if you have control over both listeners, then it might be better to conditionally call the second from the first or broadcast a second, different.  A little cleaner than using `stopImmediatePropagation`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a MouseEvent, try passing:

```
e:MouseEvent
```

as the handler's argument and not:

```
e:Event
```